# Как при добавлении новых строк в таблицу автоматически включать их значения в формулу?

Tags: excel, vba

Есть таблица в excel. Есть формулы,которые считают кол-во часов. Как мне сделать так,чтобы при добавлении строки , формула подсчета включала автоматически данные из добавленной строки?
Сумма считается простой формулой в ячейке . =СУММ(C13:C14) и т.п.

Есть скрин таблицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том,что если я добавлю "2 Цикл таких-то наук", то у меня отдельно должно посчитаться по циклу,а потом сложить все циклы вместе. вот мне надо просматривать в какой цикл вставляется строка и понимать,какую формулу из-за добавления изменять

Вот ссылка на таблицу https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/rswrd6ff4z5gea7o2wlda/.xls?dl=0&rlkey=ndgt9ah623k7j2hhj3bhvp6m4

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! Самый простой (хотя и затратный) способ - задать диапазон в формуле с большим запасом, например, `=СУММ(C13:C1000)`: пустые, ещё не заполненные ячейки, на результате не скажутся, а по мере появления новых чисел сумма будет автоматически увеличиваться. Есть и более сложные варианты формул, которые сначала подсчитывают количество заполненных строк и только потом считают их сумму, но это слишком сложно для такой простой задачи. Этот трюк работает, а значит не может считаться плохим

Comment: @JohnSUN , можете конкретнее написать про второй способ? есть проблеа в том,что расчет идет как общая сумма,так и сумма по модулям.. я об этом забыл написать. если я добавлю "2 Цикл таких-то наук", то у меня отдельно должно посчитаться по циклу,а потом сложить все циклы вместе. вот мне надо просматривать в какой цикл вставляется строка и понимать,какую формулу из-за добавления изменять

Comment: >> *сумма по модулям* -а вот для этог нужно показывать пример.

Comment: Жаль, что к вопросу приложено только изображение таблицы, а не экселевский файл-пример (так скучно перенабирать текстовую таблицу руками!). Кроме того, по изображению не совсем понятно, как нумеруются составные части каждого цикла - что за значение в колонке А, число или строка? Для решения задачи могут потребоваться функция ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНЫЕ.ИТОГИ (SUBTOTAL) или, как указал @vikttur, СУММЕСЛИ (SUMIF) или даже СУММЕСЛИМН - выбор способа зависит от исходных данных.

Comment: @JohnSUN можно ли здесь прикрепить файл?

Comment: Ах да, я не учёл, что это тоже следует объяснить. Сам ресурс не позволяет присоединять [**файлы с данными к вопросу**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47692/851458). Поэтому файл нужно разместить, например, на Google-Диске или в Dropbox, получить на него ссылку и только эту ссылку добавить к вопросу или к следующему комментарию

Comment: Цикл в первом столбце нумеруется целым числом? Так зачем суммировать, если можно найти название цикла и из этой строки получить уже известную сумму?

Comment: @vikttur не понял как это сделать. можно пример?

Comment: @JohnSUN ссылку я добавил,спасибо

Comment: @vikttur  если у меня заранее неизвестны названия этих модулей,а точно будет понятно,что есть нумерация в первом столбце? если это просто 1 или 2 ,или 4,то это модуль...если 1.2 или 4.1 , то это часть модуля... как это прописать?

Comment: *=ВПР(2;A:C;3;0)*, где 2 - номер модуля

Comment: @vikttur с помощью фун-ии ВПР задается диапазон? а дальше мне суммировать надо? =СУММ(ВПР()). так?

Comment: @vikttur ВПР это же функция поиска,нет?

Comment: Вам же надо получить сумму по модулю? Не надо суммировать! В строке с названием модуля УЖЕ ЕСТЬ СУММА. `ВПР` извлекает  значение ДЛЯ КОНКРЕТНОГО РАЗДЕЛА

Comment: @vikttur не понимаю..так а в какую ячейку записывать тогда ВПР?

Comment: Да хоть в конец листа... Туда, где Вы хотите получить результат,

Comment: @vikttur ВПР(2;A:C;3;0), 2 номер модуля, 3 и 0 это что?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122405/discussion-between-vikttur-and-qwertyui).

Answer (score 0):

Определяем положение последнего числа в столбце:

```
=СУММ(C3:ИНДЕКС(C:C;ПРОСМОТР(9E+307;C3:C1000;СТРОКА(C3:C1000))))
```

Сложно...

Один из недостатков суммирования в диапазоне, заданном с запасом - при удалении строк диапазон суммирования уменьшается и возможен случай, когда в сумму будут попадать не все значения.

Можно задать статичный диапазон, на который не влияет добавление/удаление строк:

```
=СУММ(C3:ИНДЕКС(C:C;1000)
```

Но такой вариант не избавляет от лишних вычислений в пустых строках.

Функция `СУММЕСЛИ` умеет определять используемый диапазон, поэтому просматривать будет ровно столько строк, сколько нужно:

```
=СУММЕСЛИ(C:C;">0")
```

Или по значению другого столбца:

```
 =СУММЕСЛИ(B:B;"модуль1";C:C)
```

Важно: такая формула должна быть записана не в столбце суммирования.

Если условия суммирования добавляются (например, значение других столбцов, диапазон дат...), можно использовать более продвнутую сестричку - `СУММЕСЛИМН`

Comment: я обновила скрин. файл не знаю как вствить тут. если я хочу довить строку в модуль "1 Цикл", то мне нужно использовать СУММЕСЛИ и диапазон?

Comment: Для работы функции модуль должен быть указан в каждой строке, значение которой должно суммироваться. Или в каждой строке должен быть указан какой-ибо определитель модуля. Например, нумерация в  столбце